# Log4j1.x -> Log4j2 properties files to xml

Tags: log4j, log4j2

I have read the migration page [here](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/migration.html) and am a little confused on how to complete the migration. Do I need to translate log4j1.x xml files to log4j2 xml format if I am using the bridge? and if I am programmatically configuring the loggers?

Answer (score 1):

There are no migration tools at the moment (as far as I know). However, as it says on that referenced migration page:

> For the most part, converting from the Log4j 1.x API to Log4j 2 should be fairly simple. Many of the log statements will require no modification.

So if you have any issues doing the migration, we're happy to help here on SO!

Comment: The log statements should be fine but I have been tasked with translating specific .properties files to .xml that are usable in log4j2. I have found tools like [this](https://log4j-props2xml.appspot.com/) which seem to work for the most part, but also have missed somethings? If I find an example I will link it

Comment: Gotcha. What was missing when you tried to do the conversion? Maybe we can tackle those specific cases

Comment: The problem I have noew is that I have successfully converted from log4j1 .properties to log4j1 .xml format. I however need to convert that to log4j2 .xml format for use with the new API. Is there a conversion tool? or functionality to convert within the new API?

Comment: Basically, that's where I've found that there's no conversion tool, however, if you need help doing the conversion, I'd be happy to help